# godoc Example output with CRLF

Tags: go, automated-tests, documentation-generation, godoc

I have written the following method:

```
func (c *Component) Encode(w io.Writer){
    //encodes c and writes the bytes into w, containing a few CRLF linebreaks
}
```

I also wrote the function demonstrating the encoder:

```
func ExampleComponent_Encode() {

    c := &Component{
        Name: "DESCRIPTION",
    }
    c.Encode(os.Stdout)
    //Output:
    //BEGIN:DESCRIPTION
    //END:DESCRIPTION
}
```

The Problem is now that this example fails the `go test` command because the linebreaks in the comments are \n linebreaks (I'm on Linux) while the linebreaks generated by `c.Encode` have to be \r\n(CRLF) linebreaks (as defined by some spec).

How can i get the example to not fail `go test` while also keeping it straightforward? Is there perhaps a way to hint go test/godoc on the linebreaks or get them to be more lenient?

I propably can hand-edit the linebreaks on these two lines or possibly the whole codebase but that will be pretty fragile and I want to avoid this solution.

Comment: Don't include the output in the example (or at least omit the `Output:`) header. Verify the correctness in a test instead.

Comment: https://go.dev/issues/28822 contains some discussion. Using fmt.Print("\n") instead of fmt.Println() is a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Redirect the `Encode` `io.Writer` to a buffer. In the buffer, replace CRLF (`\r\n`) with LF (`\n`) for the example output. For example,

`example_test.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type Component struct{ Name string }

func (c *Component) Encode(w io.Writer) {
    //encodes c and writes the bytes into w, containing a few CRLF linebreaks
    w.Write([]byte("BEGIN:" + c.Name + "\r\n"))
    w.Write([]byte("END:" + c.Name + "\r\n"))
}

func ExampleComponent_Encode() {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    c := &Component{
        Name: "DESCRIPTION",
    }
    c.Encode(&buf)

    output := strings.Replace(buf.String(), "\r\n", "\n", -1)
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "%s", output)
    //Output:
    //BEGIN:DESCRIPTION
    //END:DESCRIPTION
}
```

Output:

```
$ go test -v example_test.go
=== RUN   ExampleComponent_Encode
--- PASS: ExampleComponent_Encode (0.00s)
PASS
```